# Why instance variable not invoke method not override in Upcasting?

Tags: java, polymorphism, runtime

I have parent class Animal and subclass Dog

```
public class Animal {
public void bark() {
    System.out.println("sua");
}
```

}

and

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
public void bark() {
    System.out.println("Go go");
}
public void eat(){
    System.out.println("an com");
}
```

}

and class main

```
public class MainDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal = new Dog();
    animal.bark();
    animal.eat();
}
```

}

why instance animal not invoke method eat, during polymorphism runtime

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The method eat() is undefined for the type Animal

```
at tinhdahinh.MainDemo.main(MainDemo.java:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The base class must declare any method that is overridden by derived classes. It doesn't have to implement them, but the method must be declared so that when a derived object of base class calls the method the virtual despatcher knows how to route the call to the right place.
In `Animal` class, add this declaration:

```
abstract void eat();
```

This approach forces derived classes to implement `eat` method. If you don't want to force them to have an `eat` method, provide an empty implementation:

```
public void eat() { }
```